# how can I add this object in an array?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add `{[]}` in an array?

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Inside of objects, each value needs to have an associated property. Try something like `{ arr: [] }` instead

Comment: `{[]}` isn't a valid javascript construct

Comment: @JaromandaX If `{[]}` were interpreted as a block, it would be.

Comment: OK, so `[{[]}]` isn't valid :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CertainPerformance is correct. You have to have an associated property if you want to have objects.

`var a = [ { propertyName : [] } ]`

then you can access that array like this :

`a[0].propertyName` or `a[0]['propertyName']`

And you can have multiple values inside the object too :

```
var a = [
          {
            propertyName_1 : [],
            propertyName_2 : "",
            propertyName_3 : 3,
          }
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [{}] // no problem, you are assigning an empty object `{}` as first element of array
var a = [[]] // no problem, you are assigning an empty array `[]` as first element of array
var a = [{[]}] // Not working because you're assigning empty array into object
               //object needs key to store value

var a = {[]} //Not ok <<======== have you ever see var a = { 1, 2, 3} ?
```

Please refer to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects):

> An object is a collection of properties, and a property is an association between a name (or key) and a value.